# Why does cross validation RF classification perform worse than without cross validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I am puzzled why a Random Forest classification model without cross-validation yields a mean accuracy score of .996, but with 5 fold cross-validation, the model's mean accuracy score is .687.

There are 275,956 samples. Class 0 = 217891, class 1 = 6073, class 2 = 51992

I am trying to predict the "TARGET" column, which is 3 classes [0,1,2]:

```
data.head()
bottom_temperature  bottom_humidity top_temperature top_humidity    external_temperature    external_humidity   weight  TARGET  
26.35   42.94   27.15   40.43   27.19   0.0  0.0    1   
36.39   82.40   33.39   49.08   29.06   0.0  0.0    1   
36.32   73.74   33.84   42.41   21.25   0.0  0.0    1
```

From the docs, the data is split into training and test

```
# link to docs http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

# Create a list of the feature column's names
features = data.columns[:7]

# View features
features
Out[]: Index([u'bottom_temperature', u'bottom_humidity', u'top_temperature',
       u'top_humidity', u'external_temperature', u'external_humidity',
       u'weight'],
      dtype='object')


#split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data[features], data.TARGET, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

#build model
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

#predict
preds = clf.predict(X_test)

#accuracy of predictions
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, preds)
print('Mean accuracy score:', accuracy)

('Mean accuracy score:', 0.96607267423425713)

#verify - its the same
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
0.96607267423425713
```

Onto the cross validation:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(clf, data[features], data.TARGET, cv=5)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))

Accuracy: 0.69 (+/- 0.07)
```

It is much lower!

And to verify a second way:

```
#predict with CV
# http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
predicted = cross_val_predict(clf, data[features], data.queen3, cv=5)
metrics.accuracy_score(data.queen3, predicted) 

Out[]: 0.68741031178883594
```

From my understanding, Cross validation should not decrease the accuracy of predictions by this amount, but improve the model's prediction because the model has seen a "better" representation of all the data.

Comment: What is the approximate split between your target classes (0,1 and 2)? And how many samples do you have?

Comment: Also, is your data sorted by target class?

Comment: No the data is sorted by two deleted columns: groupID and timestamp (it is a longitudinal repeated measures dataset with around 80 individual environments monitored)

Comment: @Stev, there are 275,956 samples. Class 0 = 217891, class 1 = 6073, class 2 = 51992. I put this info in the OP too. good question

Comment: `StratifiedKFold` (used in `cross_val_score`) doesn't shuffle before splitting by default. My understanding is that this means you are also trying to predict a temporal element to your data when doing cross-validation. Unlike in `train_test_split`, which randomly pulls from the dataset. As a test, try setting `cv=ms.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)`.

Comment: @Stev - that boosted mean accuracy score to 97%

Comment: So all fixed? If so, great, I'll put it as an answer because it's important that people know about this behaviour.

Comment: @Stev - Sure that is a great answer. What if i wanted to split the dataset into training/testing/validation while keeping the 80 individual environments intact? Would it be possible to add a column for groupID, and use that in the stratified k folds?

Comment: You could try using [GroupKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I would agree with Vivek and tell you to trust your cross-validation.

However, some level of CV is inherent in a random forest because each tree is grown from a bootstrapped sample, so you shouldn’t expect to see such a large reduction in accuracy when running cross-validation. I suspect your problem is due to some sort of time- or location-dependency in your data sorting.

When you use `train_test_split`, data is drawn randomly from the dataset, so all 80 of your environments are likely to be present in your train and test datasets. However, when you split using the default options for CV, I believe that each of the folds is drawn in order, so each of your environments is not present within every fold (assuming your data is ordered by environment). This leads to a lower accuracy because you are predicting one environment using data from another.

The simple solution is to set `cv=ms.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)`.

I have run into this problem several times before when using concatenated datasets and there must be hundreds of others who have and haven’t realised what the issue is. The idea of the default behaviour is to maintain order in a time series (from what I have seen in GitHub discussions).

Answer (score 4):

In the `train_test_split`, you are using 60% of data for training (`test_size=0.4`) only a single time. But in `cross_val_score` the the data will be splitted into 80% train (cv = 5) 5 times (Each time 4 folds will become the train and remaining 1 as test).

Now you should think that 80% training data is more than 60% so the accuracy should not decrease. But there is one more thing to notice here.

The `train_test_split` will not stratify the splits by default, but it will do in `cross_val_score`. Stratification is keeping the ratio of classes (targets) same in each fold. So most probably, its happening that the ratio of targets is not maintained in the train_test_split which leads to over-fitting of the classifier and hence this high score.

I would suggest to take the cross_val_score as final score.

Answer (score 2):

Your data likely has some inherent order to it. Change "shuffle" to true when you are doing CV.